# Making MagicTextView a library causing R can not resolved to a variable

Tags: android, textview, rjava

I was trying to import MagicTextView to my project so that I could make the TextView's innerflow visible. I import it using the File->import->Existing Project into workspace and make it a Library by clicking on "Is Library" of "Android" tab of Property of the project.

I then open up my project go to Android property of Property and clicked on Add and add MagicTextView as Library and then I received R can not be resolved to a variable in my project cause below xml errors in MagicTextView.

```
 error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'strokeWidth' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout /main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'foreground' in package   'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'innerShadowDy' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'innerShadowColor' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'innerShadowRadius' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'outerShadowDy' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'outerShadowColor' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'outerShadowRadius' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'strokeColor' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'strokeJoinStyle' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:30 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'strokeWidth' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'foreground' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'innerShadowDy' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'innerShadowColor' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'innerShadowRadius' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'outerShadowDy' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'outerShadowColor' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'outerShadowRadius' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'strokeColor' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'strokeJoinStyle' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
[2013-12-09 14:49:31 - CCC] /home/asutosh/workspace/MagicTextView/res/layout/main.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'strokeWidth' in package 'com.qwerjk.better_text'
```

However all these attributes are defined in attr of values in res.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same problem..
Don't use it as library. Copy the MagicTextView.java file and all the related resources in your very project and then use it. It will do the trick.

Comment: what should I write instead of these following lines in my xml file where I want to show TextView

<com.qwerjk.better_text.MagicTextView
        xmlns:qwerjk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.qwerjk.better_text"

Comment: Replace "com.qwerjk.better_text.MagicTextView" by the path where you are pasting this MagicTextView.java file, rest all remains same.

Comment: Abhishek Shukla :- it shows Unbounf prefix,parse xml error I replace the above with 
<com.example.sss.MagicTextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.sss"

Comment: Remove the xmlns line and then see it

Comment: One work around is to create the object programatically. and then adding it to the layout. .some what like in the below answer

Comment: I am really sorry sorry to say Abhishek however the last line shows error.
((RelativeLayout) this.getParent()).addView(popUpScoreTextView);

Comment: Yaar, I did it in a customView class that I was using, here "this" is the reference to the object of that customView class. If you are doing it in an activity, modify it according to your needs. And, I'm sure it'll work.. :)

Comment: Did you write this chunk of code in your activity and if its a yes then popUpScoreTextView is of plain TextView or MagicTextView?

Comment: No, the code isn't in activity, it's in some other class which is a customView

Comment: Please let me know if you are doing this in a Activity and popUpScoreTextView is of MagicTextView

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
popUpScoreTextView = new MagicTextView(myContext);
    // popUpScoreTextView.addInnerShadow(0, -1, 0, 0xFFffffff);
    popUpScoreTextView.addOuterShadow(9, 0, 2, Color.BLACK);
    popUpScoreTextView.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#612d00"));
    popUpScoreTextView.setTypeface(MyTypfaces.get(myContext, "GROBOLD"));
    popUpScoreTextView.setTextSize(40);
    popUpScoreTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffb400"));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams popupScoreTextViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popupScoreTextViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    popUpScoreTextView.setLayoutParams(popupScoreTextViewParams);
    // ((GamePlayActivity)myContext).addContentView(popUpScoreTextView,
    // popupScoreTextViewParams);
    popUpScoreTextView.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);

    if (popUpScoreTextView.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) popUpScoreTextView.getParent())
                .removeView(popUpScoreTextView);

    // popUpScoreTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,
    // Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
    ((RelativeLayout) this.getParent()).addView(popUpScoreTextView);
```